# jquery issue with $(document).on drops variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, document

i have this code with out the (doc on) it work in tell the div is reloaded after the reload the buttons do not work. With (doc on) the event fires but drops the variables any ideas?

```
 $(document).on(".status").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ids = $(this).attr("data-id-status");
    var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
    var record = this;
    $(record).attr('class', 'btn btn-danger big-bnt prams');
    $(record).prop('disabled', true);
    $(record).html('Precessing');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {action: 'status', id: ids, status: status},
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == '0') {
                $('#flag-view').fadeOut(800, function () {
                    $("#r" + ids).remove();
                    $('#flag-view').fadeIn().delay(2000);
                });
            }
            else if (data == '2') {

            }
            else if (data == '3') {

            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    }); // end ajax call
})
```

Comment: What you mean by "he event fires but drops the variables" can you please explain more?

Comment: the jquery event of the click run im able to add a alert and it show up on the screen

Comment: event delegation, just saying.  When you replace things with Ajax, you lose any bindings directly set on those elements.  The answers posted are binding the event on document, and delegating the `click` to your element (basically, without explaining bubbling).  So when a click happens in the document, it searches for your element.  Instead of it being bound directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration is incorrect change

From

```
$(document).on(".status").click(function (event) {
```

To

```
$(document).on("click", ".status", function(event){
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not how [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) works.

[`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) is a helper function that is used for adding event handlers to an element (with an optional selector), like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".status", function (event) {
    // Do your stuff here
});
```

Doing it like this (providing a selector) makes it into a delegated handler. Only one event handler is added to the `document` and any events that bubble up will be caught and given to the callback function.

You can also add the event handler directly to an element (or a collection of elements), like so:

```
$(document).find(".status").on("click", function (event) {
    // ...
});
```

If the `.status` elements the handler was added to are removed then the handler will also be removed.

Event handling in jQuery can be a little confusing at first but it is quite logical. I would suggest that you [read up on it](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to get a better sense of how it works.